# When to rely on RVO vs move semantics in C++?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, return-value-optimization

Say I have some expensive class `X`, and take this code:

```
X functor() {
    X x;
    //do stuff
    return x;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<X> vec;
    vec.push_back(functor());
    vec.push_back(std::move(functor()));

    return 0;
}
```

Which `push_back` is more efficient? In the first case, won't the NRVO be activated and prevent the copy as the move does? Should I be relying on the NRVO instead of doing manual moving, since the NRVO is basically automatic moving?

Comment: Do you have a *measurable* performance problem you're trying to fix?

Comment: @tadman I'm just confused on why you would ever want to move something if the move optimization can be automatic with the RVO.

Comment: Using `move` seems superfluous

Comment: C++ gives you a lot of tools that you probably don't need, may never need, but they're there because some people need them some of the time. I wouldn't stress out about this. It's there *if* you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither piece of code is more efficient; they do the exact same thing. And neither `push_back` expression involves elision of any kind. The only actual elision happened back in the `return` statement, which the `push_back` expressions don't interact with.

In both `push_back` expressions, the prvalue returned by the function will manifest a temporary. In the latter case, the temporary will be cast into an xvalue, but that doesn't represent any actual runtime changes. Both versions will call the same `push_back` overload: the one which takes an rvalue reference. And therefore in both cases the return value will be moved from.

Answer (score 3):

@Nichol Bolas' answer is correct, as far as it goes.

It seems to me that you don't entirely understand what `std::move` does, or when it's intended to be used.

`std::move` is (at least primarily) used when you have a parameter or rvalue reference type, something like this: `int foo(int &&param);`. The problem is that even though `param` has to be initialized from an rvalue, and refers to an rvalue, `param` itself has a name (i.e., param) so it is not itself an rvalue. Because of that, the compiler can't/won't automatically recognize that `param` can be used as the source of a move operation. So, if you want to do a move out of `param`, you need to use `std::move` to tell the compiler that this is an rvalue, so the compiler can move from it instead of copying from it.

In your code: `vec.push_back(std::move(functor()));`, you're applying the `std::move` to the temporary value that holds the return from the function. Since this is a temporary rather than a named variable, the compiler can/will automatically recognize that it can be used as the source of a move, so `std::move` has no hope of accomplishing anything.

Although it doesn't really apply in this specific case, the other point to keep in mind for situations somewhat like this is using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`. This can allow your code to avoid building and then copying/moving an object at all. Instead, it can create references to the parameters that you pass to the ctor to create the object, so that inside of `emplace_back` itself, you create an object (once) in the spot it's going to occupy in the target vector. For example:

```cpp
struct foo { 
    int i;
    double d;

    foo(int i, double d) : i(i), d(d) {}
};

std::vector<foo> f;

int a = 123;
double b = 456.789;

f.push_back(foo(a, b));
f.emplace_back(a, b);
```

In this case, the `push_back` creates a temporary `foo` object, initialized from `a` and `b` . Since that's a temporary, the compiler recognizes that it can do a move from there into the spot it's going to occupy in the vector.

But the `emplace_back` avoids creating the temporary at all. Instead, it just passes references to `a` and `b`, and inside of `emplace_back`, when it's ready to create the object in the `vector`, it creates it, initializing it directly from `a` and `b`.

`foo` directly contains data, rather than containing a pointer to the data. That mean in this case, doing a move is likely to gain little or nothing compared to doing a copy, so even though `push_back` can accept an rvalue and do a move out of it into the target, it wont' do much good in this case--it'll end up copying the data anyway. But with `emplace_back`, we'll avoid that completely, and just initialize the object directly from the source data (`a` and `b`), so we'll copy them once--but only once.

Answer (score 1):

NRVO implies that automatic storage described by `x` is identical to storage referenced by rvalue result of `functor()` call. `std::move()` in this case is late for the party and gets no credit.